# CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(String) no reconoce algunas referencias culturales

Tags: c#

El caso es que estoy haciendo pruebas para una app multilenguaje en c#. Tengo estas lineas:

```
rsp = Console.ReadLine();

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(rsp);
Console.WriteLine(strings.strings.Hello);
```

En la carpeta strings tengo varios archivos de recursos .resx con el valor de `Hello` para varios idiomas. La mayoría de las referencias que meto en `rsp` las reconoce y saca el valor de `Hello` desde el `resx` de ese idioma.

Sin embargo, hay algunas que no reconoce; por ejemplo `en-CA`, `ru`, `ja`, `ja-JP`.

En la imagen se ve el contenido de mi carpeta strings, por lo que el japonés, el ruso y el ingles de Canadá deberían salir. Pero no salen, sale el valor de `strings.resx` (que es el recurso por defecto).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estás seguro? Yo acabo de hacer una prueba rápida con dos archivos de recursos,uno genérico y otro con `en-CA` y me ha funcionado correctamente.

Comment: He probado por si era un problema de codificación de caracteres también con `ja-JP` y también funciona. Fíjate a ver si en los archivos de recursos que te fallan el nombre de la cadena es exactamente el mismo que en los otros.

Comment: Ya me di cuenta, no eran exactamente igual, el error siempre es lo más simple y estupido